# How to statement RLMArray type add NSString

Tags: realm

How can I statement a `RLMArray` for `NSString` type in Objective-C?

Like this:

```
@property RLMArray<Dog> *dogs;
```

Comment: Please format your pseudo-code by adding 4 leading space to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#many-to-many (since Realm 3.0.0+):

> RLMArrays can store primitive values in lieu of Realm objects. In order to do so, constrain a RLMArray with one of the following protocols: RLMBool, RLMInt, RLMFloat, RLMDouble, RLMString, RLMData, or RLMDate.

So you need to use

```
@property RLMArray<RLMString> *names;
```

---

Notes for Realm-Objective-C 3.0.0:

> Querying RLMArrays containing values other than
>   RLMObject subclasses is not yet implemented.